# Problem with passing props to component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component

I'm very new to Vue.

I have a component and there is a multiselect component in it. I pass a value to my component and pass that value to multiselect. Most of times I can't see that value but sometimes, when I save the code and npm rerun the code I can see the result but it's rare.

Here my component's template part:

```
  <template>
  <div>
     <multiselect
       :value="defaultValue"
       v-model="value"
       ...
     </multiselect>
  </div>
  </template>
```

The script part:

```
props: [some other things, "defaultValue"],
data() {
    return {
      value: this.defaultValue,
    }
  },
```

And I pass that prop as like that:

```
<MyComponent other things... :defaultValue="station"/>
```

This is current situation:
[image: Where I am]

And this is what I want to see when I load the page:
[image: I want to be]

What is my problem?

Edit: By the way when I pass v-model="defaultValue" to my multiselect it works but in that way I can't change the value because as I understand the props are inmutable in Vue.

Comment: You are using `value` inside v-model. Where is it coming from?

Comment: From data in the script part.

Comment: do you want to emit the selected value to the parent component?

Comment: Yes I want to do that. But also I want to get the first value from parent.

Comment: Does the variable `station` exists in your component?

Comment: I get that in data function in parent like that : station: this.$store.state.common.x.y

Answer (score 0):

### Don't bind both `v-model` and `:value`

They are both trying to control the same underlying feature.

### Debugging

I see your remark that just using v-model doesn't work.

Change your code to show some debugging information:

```
  <template>
  <div>

     <p>defaultValue is: {{defaultValue}}</p>
     <p>value is: {{value}}</p>

     <multiselect
       v-model="value"
       ...
     </multiselect>
  </div>
  </template>
```

The reason this is important, is that we currently don't know what values are being fed into this component inside `this.defaultValue`.

We can see this:

```
<MyComponent other things... :defaultValue="station"/>
```

but we don't know what the value of the variable `this.station` in your parent component is. It might not be one of the possible values of multiselect.

The debugging step will help resolve that.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Try the debugging step and please report exactly what is displayed, perhaps as a screenshot within the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `defaultvalue` a default value in your component, specifically you can have two ways:

You can pass a non-null value using the parent component.

or

Use the watch method to monitor your `defaultvalue`, and when it is empty, give `defaultvalue` a default value.

parent component:

```js
<multi-select :default-value="selectValue" />
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    selectValue: '', // you can set null or '' or '1' or '3' or '2'
  };
}
```

child component:

```html
<select v-model="selectValue">
   <option
     v-for="(item, index) in selectArray"
     :key="index"
     :value="item.value"
   >
   {{ item.label }}
   </option>
</select>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'MultiSelect',
  props: {
    defaultValue: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectArray: [
        { value: '1', label: 'Value 1' },
        { value: '2', label: 'Value 2' },
        { value: '3', label: 'Value 3' },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    selectValue: {
      get() {
        if (!this.defaultValue) {
          return '1';
        }
        return this.defaultValue
      },
      set(newVal) {
        console.log(newVal);
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Do you think it comes empty to my component? Actually I try to log it in data function and I can see that it has a value.

Comment: @I2mNew Wait, I write an example for you.

Comment: @I2mNew [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-jduzaf?file=src/components/multi-select.vue)